# Ok() vs Ok(null)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

What's the difference between `Ok()` vs `Ok(null)`?

The `Ok(null)` returns status code **204** with no body but header, therefore we have to change our code in this way:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetTest(string test)
{
    MyClass result = GetMyClass(test)
    if(result == null) return Ok();
    return Ok(result);
}
```

Comment: You seem to of answered your own question?

Comment: @Liam the question is "Why" ;)

Comment: why what? *Ok() vs Ok(null), why?* That question doesn't make a lot of sense either.

Comment: **See Also**: [Ok(null) vs NoContent() in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59861379/1366033)

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you use `NoContent` (`HttpStatus 204`).

That means the request successfully executed, but didn't return a value or object, and it's an official status code for this purpose

See the following example:

```cs
[HttpGet()]
public IActionResult GetTest(string test)
{
    var result = GetMyClass(test)
    return result != null
        ? Ok(result)
        : NoContent();
}
```

Hope you'll find this useful.

Answer (score 1):

Official documentation says

> Ok()   Creates a OkResult object that produces an empty Status200OK
>   response.
>
> Ok(Object)     Creates an OkObjectResult object that produces an
>   Status200OK response.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.ok?view=aspnetcore-2.1

When you pass null , it will creates an OkObjectResult of null , So you are getting 204 status code.

Comment: @Liam yes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204

Comment: @JEMI - Did you read that link? It says "The HTTP 204 No Content **success** status response code". Success implying that no error occurred...

Comment: In this case as the method is called GetSomething I presume there should be a response so this is not the correct thing to respond with... presumably a 404 (Resource not found) would be more appropriate than an OK status or indeed a No Content status

Comment: @JEMI - Yes, I knew what you meant, but other readers may be confused of your use of the word 'error' as that has a specific meaning which in this case the code does not donate an error

Comment: @Milney Ok..got it..my mistake

Answer (score 1):

HTTP status code [**`204`**](https://httpstatuses.com/204) is a valid "success" result that lets the recipient know that there is no content. This actually seems rather appropriate, but still it may not be supported everywhere.

Either your could 'teach' (or program) your recipient to handle it correctly, or you need to apply your workaround.

If you need this workaround in multiple places then you could use a base class to overload `Ok()` (or more precisely, redefine it) to always do what you need, like this:

```
public abstract class MyBaseApiController : ApiController
{
    public new IHttpActionResult Ok<T>(T content)
    {
        if (content == null) return base.Ok();
        return base.Ok(content);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can I not find `ApiController` to inherit from? VS suggests either `ApiControllerBase` or `ApiControllerAttribute`. What am I missing?