# Ok(null) vs NoContent() in ASP.NET Core - which is more efficient?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, optimization

Both end up producing an empty 204 status response, but which one is faster?

Obviously if you follow the DRY guidelines, it's much cleaner to write

```
return Ok(something);
```

rather than

```
if (something == null)
{
    return NoContent()
}
else
{
    return Ok(something);
}
```

After checking the source, `NoContent()` translates to calling `StatusCode(204)`, as for `Ok(null)` I didn't dive deep enough to see where exactly they check (if at all they do) for a null value, and if it's null, decide to return a StatusCode 204 (or handle it some other way).

I personally think that `NoContent()` will yield faster performance, even though the difference we'll be talking about is in the fractions of a second.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you call `return NoContent()`, it returns the `StatusCodeResult` [`NoContentResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.nocontentresult?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

When a `StatusCodeResult` is to be executed, all it does is [setting the status code on the response](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/7e10a98c4f303b9af36047a0c61f1fbf038ccda8/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/StatusCodeResult.cs#L35):

```
public override void ExecuteResult(ActionContext context)
{
    // snip boilerplate code

    context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCode;
}
```

Now when you call `return Ok(something)`, what actually gets returned is an `OkObjectResult(something)`. And as its name implies, an [`OkObjectResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.okobjectresult?view=aspnetcore-3.1) is an [`ObjectResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.objectresult?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

And there are many, many ways an object result can be written to the output, and that's where MVC's internals kick in.

When the response is to be executed, in the case of the `ObjectResult`, [the registered `IActionResultExecutor<ObjectResult>` is resolved and `ExecuteAsync()` is called](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/00846a232c58db75c8477c9288af23508e055711/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ObjectResult.cs#L41).

When using the default MVC registrations, this is the [`ObjectResultExecutor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.infrastructure.objectresultexecutor?view=aspnetcore-3.1). Its [`ExecuteAsync()`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/d5fd9fc2faeb079e05e3db31e29dcdea31841eec/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/ObjectResultExecutor.cs#L98) offloads its formatter selection (i.e. which of the registered formatters to use for actually writing the provided ObjectResult onto the wire) to the aptly named `OutputFormatterSelector` which it gets injected in its constructor.

And of course, by default, that is the [`DefaultOutputFormatterSelector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.infrastructure.defaultoutputformatterselector?view=aspnetcore-3.1). Now *this* class [pulls its output formatters](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/7003fb53d542de6f4bf999f2edaa91c6951e1be0/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/DefaultOutputFormatterSelector.cs#L43) from [`MvcOptions.OutputFormatters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.mvcoptions.outputformatters?view=aspnetcore-3.1), which in the [default configuration](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/2e4274cb67c049055e321c18cc9e64562da52dcf/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/MvcCoreMvcOptionsSetup.cs#L86) contains:

- HttpNoContentOutputFormatter
- StringOutputFormatter
- StreamOutputFormatter
- SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter

In that order. Now for the actual selection (ignoring the content negotiation code, as there is no content here), the selector iterates over the registered formatters and chooses the first one that [returns `true` for `CanWriteResult()`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/7003fb53d542de6f4bf999f2edaa91c6951e1be0/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/DefaultOutputFormatterSelector.cs#L198). And if the `HttpNoContentOutputFormatter` is set to `TreatNullValueAsNoContent`, which it is by default, *and* the `Object` to return is `null`, then it does return just that.

Then some more code runs, and finally `WriteAsync()` is called on that formatter, [doing this](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Formatters/HttpNoContentOutputFormatter.cs#L35):

```
public Task WriteAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context)
{
    var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
    response.ContentLength = 0;

    if (response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status200OK)
    {
        response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status204NoContent;
    }

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

So yeah, a lot more code runs. But whether that's actually noticeable, should be benchmarked by you.

Now whether you actually *want* `Ok(null)` to return a 204 instead of a 200 is [up for debate](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/8847); you can opt out of it using this code in your startup:

```
services.AddMvc(options => 
{
    var noContentFormatter = options.OutputFormatters.OfType<HttpNoContentOutputFormatter>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (noContentFormatter != null)
    {
        noContentFormatter.TreatNullValueAsNoContent = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: You are a wizard! What an insightful and well-detailed answer! Do you have any general pointers to people that wish to venture into the forest you delve in? I'd love to know all these small details, but reading a project as big as aspnetcore is very hard for me. I'll add bounty to your answer when I'm eligible to do so.

Comment: Thanks! I've been using MVC and WebAPI for years, and plenty of times I had to do a deep dive into the source to find out where things happened and why. In the beginning, people (Hanselman, Guthrie and others) used to blog about how it all worked, but with the advent of Core, I can't find that detailed information anymore, unfortunately. Maybe that's my cue to start blogging again, or even better, start writing documentation the project has been lacking for years...

Comment: There are a few core components though that could get you up to speed. See routing  and areas (which request ends up where), model binding (convert input to objects), content negotiation and output formatting (convert objects to output), view engines (who uses something else than Razor though?) and conventions (loads of written and unwritten rules that determine what happens based on names of things).